# bottom sheet перестает реагировать после поворота экрана

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, material-design

Дело скорее не в нем самом, а в способах передачи объекта.На самом то деле смущает привязка bottom sheet к `CoordinatorLayout`.

Есть некий `Bottom Sheet` в главной активити. А так же список `RecyclerView` в фрагменте, и в котором есть кнопка, по нажатию на которую вызывается `Bottom Sheet`из активити.

Проблема состоит в том, что после поворота экрана, он перестает вызываться.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private BottomSheetBehavior behavior;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private FrameLayout frameSheet;
private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
private View bottomSheet;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initToolbar();
    initNavigationDrawer();
    initTabs();
    initBottomSheetBehavior();
}





private static void hideSheet(View bottomSheet, final BottomSheetBehavior behavior){
    bottomSheet.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
        }
    });
}

private void initBottomSheetBehavior() {
  //  RecycleFragment frag = (RecycleFragment )getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.recyclefragment123456);


    frameSheet = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.framesheet);

    coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinator);
    coordinatorLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    bottomSheet = coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.framesheet);
    behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    Log.d("Sheet", "behavior " + behavior);
 //   hideSheet(bottomSheet,behavior);
    RecycleFragment.getInstance().setContext(this);
    RecycleFragment.getInstance().setBehaviorSheet(behavior, frameSheet);

    behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BehaviorController(behavior));


}

public  BottomSheetBehavior getBehavior(){
    return behavior;
}
```

Поскольку сохранение состояния происходит через `setRetainInstance()` я определенно что-то упустил, но ошибку найти никак не удается.

Вызов `Bottom Sheet`

```
public class InfoBtnClick implements View.OnClickListener {
private BottomSheetBehavior behavior;
private boolean isExpanded;

public InfoBtnClick(BottomSheetBehavior behavior) {
    this.behavior = behavior;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d("Sheet", "info click called");
    if (isExpanded) {
        behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
    } else {
        behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    }
    isExpanded = !isExpanded;
}
```

Фрагмент:

```
public class RecycleFragment extends Fragment {
private static final int LAYOUT = R.layout.fragment_recycle;
private View view;
private RecyclerView rvContacts;
private RvWordsAdapter adapter;
private List<Word> words;
private BottomSheetBehavior behavior;
private Context context;
private FrameLayout frameLayout;

public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    initRecyclerView(view, context, this.behavior);
}


public static RecycleFragment getInstance() {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    RecycleFragment recycleFragment = new RecycleFragment();
    recycleFragment.setArguments(args);

    return recycleFragment;
}

public void setBehaviorSheet(BottomSheetBehavior behavior, FrameLayout frameLayout) {
    this.behavior = behavior;
    Log.d("Sheet", "behavior setBehaviorSheet" + behavior.getState());
}

private List<Word> getWords() {
    if (words == null) {
        return createMock();
    }
    return words;
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, container, false);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    behavior = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getBehavior();
    frameLayout = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getFrameSheet();


    //     final View subjectLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycle, null);
    final LinearLayout subheader = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.subheader);

  /*  view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            subheader.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    },5);*/

    Log.d("Sheet", "behavior onCreateView" + this.behavior);
    return view;
}

private void initRecyclerView(View view, Context context, BottomSheetBehavior behavior) {
    rvContacts = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvWords);
    if (adapter == null) {
        adapter = new RvWordsAdapter(getWords(), getActivity(), behavior, frameLayout);
    }
    rvContacts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    rvContacts.setAdapter(adapter);


    frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

Пример использования фрагмента:

```
  @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return RecycleFragment.getInstance();
        case 1:
            return RecycleFragment.getInstance();
        case 2:
            return RecycleFragment.getInstance();
        case 3:
            return RecycleFragment.getInstance();
        case 4:
            return RecycleFragment.getInstance();
        case 5:
            return RecycleFragment.getInstance();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Есть подозрение, что вы потеряли фрагмент. Покажите как вы его добавляете, видимо тут `RecycleFragment.getInstance().setContext(this);` Расшифруйте.

Comment: @YuraIvanov обновил, через `getInstance()` созданному экземляру присваиваю контекст

Comment: Не совсем понятно где вы его добавляете в fragmentManager или он у вас в разметке (тогда нужно его искать его в fragmentManager'е, а не новый создавать)? И вы же понимаете, что каждый вызов getInstance возвращает новый объект фрагмента?

Comment: @YuraIvanov я без fragmentManager'a , разве инстанс фрагмента не сохраняется при повороте и прочем?Ведь `setRetainInstance()` удаляет лишь внешнее представление, сохраняя экземпляр.
Либо я что-то не правильно понимаю?

Comment: Ох, я кажется понял, на какой момент Вы намекаете.Только не совсем представляю, как лучше это решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подробно как правильно работать с активити из фрагментов написано в [доках](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). У вас это может выглядеть примерно так:

1. Объявляете интерфейс

   ```
   public interface FragmentCallbacks {
       void toggle(String word);
   }
   ```
2. Реализуете интерфейс в MainActivity

   ```
   public class MainActivity ... implements FragmentCallbacks {

        @Override
        public void toggle(String word){
            if(behavior.getState()==BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED){
                behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                //foobarTextView.setText(word);
            } else
                behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        }
   }
   ```
3. В фрагменте преобразуете контекст в переменную с типом интерфейса. И из адаптера вызываете соответствующий (в данном случае он один) метод.

   ```
    public class RecycleFragment extends Fragment {

       private FragmentCallbacks mCallbacksListener;

       @Override 
       public void onAttach(Context context){
           if(context instanceof FragmentCallbacks){
               mCallbacksListener = (FragmentCallbacks)context;
           } else {
               throw new IllegalStateException("Context must implement FragmentCallbacks interface");
           }
       }

       private class RvWordsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapater<...>{
           @Override
           public void onBindViewHolder(...){
               ...
               holder.infoView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       mCallbacksListener.toggle(words.get(position));
                   }
               });
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Профит. Т.е. никакие behavior и проч пробрасывать не надо и перепробрасывать при поворотах тоже, фрагмент сам переподпишется и будет вызывать правильный колбэк, когда activity пересоздастся. И есть подозрение, что InfoBtnClick вам не нужен, активити сама разберется показывать или прятать, если что...

N.B. Нюанс заключается в том, что адаптер должен быть внутренним классом фрагмента, в противном случае точно также придется пробрасывать интерфейс (какой-то скорее всего другой) из фрагмента в адаптер, иначе в адаптере будет после поворота старая ссылка на контекст активити. Ну или придется [пере]создавать адаптер в onAttach... Впрочем, этим можно пока не заморачиваться, а разобраться позже, поняв принцип.

См. также в википедии:

- [Инверсия управления](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)
- [Внедрение зависимости](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)
- и далее по ссылкам...